# How to cast a mmap.mmap Python object into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I'm making a [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) powered program and I use the `yield` keyword with `mmap.mmap` object to send multiples mapped files in the output stream like in this code :

```py
for mapping in mappings:
  yield mapping
```

This doesn't work out of the box because Bottle [want a `string`](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content) (see *Iterables and generators* section) and when I use `str(mapping)`, this return the object itself not the content.

So, I want to **cast the `mmap` object into a `string`** which contain the file content.

*I'm thinking as the C programmer who just want to put a raw pointer*

Comment: Just asking, but what are you referring to when you say bottle wants a string?

Comment: Also what’s the purpose of using mmap? As in what are you sending? The entire file or just part of it?

Comment: @Jab Sorry, I forgot to put links, the [doc](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content) say that `You are allowed to use yield within your callbacks or return an iterable, as long as the iterable yields byte strings`. I use mmap to send the entire file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Googling for hours. I found out that simply using `bytes(mapping)` work.

```py
    for mapping in mappings:
        yield bytes(mapping)
```

This way doesn't seem to do a temporary copy of mapped data